# is "so" a conjunction here?

Tags: parsing

> Scepticism among politicians is not born only of spite. Governments
> invest in higher education to boost productivity by increasing human
> capital. But even as universities have boomed, productivity growth in
> the rich-country economies has fallen. Many politicians suspect that
> universities are not teaching the right subjects, and are producing
> more graduates than labour markets need. Small wonder that the state
> is beginning to pull back. In America government spending on
> universities has been flat in recent years; in Australia, even as the
> price of humanities degrees doubles, **so** it will fall for subjects
> the government deems good for growth.

---

If "so" is a conjunction, does that mean this sentence is a grammatically wrong as there is no main clause? And if not, what does "so" mean here?

article link : https://www.economist.com/leaders/2020/08/08/covid-19-will-be-painful-for-universities-but-also-bring-change

Comment: It's only a conjunction in kiddies' grammar and (unfortunately) most dictionaries. It's actually a preposition that can take a wide range of complementation, including finite clauses. Here's one dictionary that does get it right [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/so)

Comment: But the reason of "even as the price of humanities degrees doubles"? I don't get it